# "Marbles pulled out of a bag" style problem with no replacement and a high quantity of marbles?

Tags: probability

I know the title was probably a tad confusing, but I'll do my best to explain the problem:
So I have 37 "marbles" with varying probabilities of appearing (0.05% to 15.00%). I need to acquire a random order of each marble being drawn, but each marble must be drawn (there will be 2,000 total, therefore the rarest marble (0.05%) should appear exactly once and the most common marble (15.00%) should appear exactly 300 times).
Is this possible via an online tool? Or, even better, excel? Thanks, I would appreciate any and all help!

Comment: Could you please explain what a "random order" might be?  It sounds like you want some kind of random sample or random sequence of size 2000 according to some kind of rules related to the probabilities, but exactly what this might be is unclear.  A small example might help.  For instance, if you were to replace "37" by "2," replace "2000" by "3," and make the two probabilities, say, 43% and 57%, then what would some valid solutions be?

Comment: Hi whuber, thanks for your response. Here's a simple example: 

A size of 100. Two entities (A and B) have a rarity percentage of 40% and 60%, respectively. I need A to appear exactly 40 times and B to appear exactly 60 times, but the order in which they appear should be random. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Create a list of 2000 elements with the exact numbers you want of each type. Sample that list without replacement (for which there are several possible approaches); in excel you might generate 2000 random uniforms and sort on that column and then just take the elements in that random sort order.

(As for using an online tool, I'd probably do it in R via rdrr.io/snippets)

Answer (score 1):

Unless I've misunderstood the question, you can just generate a list with the desired number of each element, in any order, and then shuffle it.